# Crash when the screen needs to be recreated, possible problem with dependency injection (Class has no zero argument constructor)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx, dagger

I'm working on an old Android project. I know a little about Android, but my focus is iOS. So maybe I'm missing something simple here.

Problem:
The Home screen is working, but when it needs to be recreated the app crashes. Today I'm triggering it going on settings and changing the location permission.

**Error**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.x.activities, PID: 16127
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.activities/com.x.ui.home.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.xxx.activities:layout/activity_homescreen: Binary XML file line #23 in com.x.activities:layout/activity_homescreen: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.x.activities:layout/activity_homescreen: Binary XML file line #23 in com.x.activities:layout/activity_homescreen: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.x.activities:layout/activity_homescreen: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.x.ui.home.HomeViewModel
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.x.ui.homescreen.HomescreenFragment.getParentViewModel(HomescreenFragment.kt:47)
                                                                                                        at com.x.ui.homescreen.HomescreenFragment.observeParentViewModel(HomescreenFragment.kt:130)
                                                                                                        at com.x.ui.homescreen.HomescreenFragment.onViewCreated(HomescreenFragment.kt:96)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
2023-09-08 14:54:08.143 16127-16127 AndroidRuntime          com.x.activities              E     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1081)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1009)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:973)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1135)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                                                        at com.x.ui.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.x.ui.home.HomeViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
                                                                                                        ... 61 more
```

**HomescreenFragment**

```
class HomescreenFragment : BaseMvRxFragment() {

private val parentViewModel by homeViewModel() //line 47

  @Inject
  internal lateinit var viewModelFactory: HomescreenViewModel.Factory
  private val viewModel: HomescreenViewModel by fragmentViewModel()

  private val homescreenActionsController by lazy { HomescreenActionsController(requireActivity()) }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//...
        observeParentViewModel() //line 96
//...
  }

  private fun observeParentViewModel() =
        parentViewModel.permissionRequestResult.observeEvent(viewLifecycleOwner) { //line 130
            homescreenActionsController.onPermissionResult(it)
  }
//...
}
```

**HomeActivity**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HomeCallbacks, UsingLocation {

  @Inject
  lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        NetComponent.instance.inject(this)
        initDagger()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen) //line 133
///...
  }
///...
}
```

**HomeViewModel**

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userInbox: UserInbox,
    private val prefUserInfo: PrefUserInfo,
    private val prefAppInfo: PrefAppInfo,
    private val prefOrgInfo: PrefOrgInfo,
    private val realmController: RealmController,
    private val api: Api,
    private val loginState: LoginState,
    private val application: LiveSafeApplication,
    private val initializers: AppInitializer
) : ViewModel(), PushJsonConsumer {

  init {
        NetComponent.instance.inject(this)
        ///...
  }

  companion object {
        fun Fragment.homeViewModel() = activityViewModels<HomeViewModel>()
  }
}
```

**activity_homescreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" /> //line 23
    </FrameLayout>

///...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

One suggestion that I found was to replace:

`private val parentViewModel by homeViewModel()`

with

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory2: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private val parentViewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory2 }
```

if I do that the app won't crash anymore, but the code in the function observeParentViewModel isn't called, so I think I'm getting a different instance.

`parentViewModel` is only called in `observeParentViewModel` function, so I could use a different strategy if I still could call homescreenActionsController.onPermissionResult

Other suggestion was to create a custom factory to be able to have a `HomeViewModel` with no arguments, but I didn't understand how I'm going to pass the arguments to be able to create a `HomeViewModel`

The project isn't using Hilt, only Dagger.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "Class has no zero argument constructor" error in your Android project, here's a simplified and recommended solution :

1. Create a custom ViewModel Factory for `HomeViewModel` that can handle dependency injection.

```kotlin
class HomeViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    // Inject your dependencies here
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HomeViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return HomeViewModel(
                // Pass the injected dependencies here
            ) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

2. Ensure you have a Dagger module set up to provide the dependencies required by `HomeViewModel` and `HomeViewModelFactory`.

```kotlin
@Module
class AppModule {
    // Provide your dependencies here
}
```

3. Update your `HomescreenFragment` to use the ViewModel with the custom factory for proper dependency injection.

```kotlin
class HomescreenFragment : BaseMvRxFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: HomeViewModelFactory

    private val parentViewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }

    // ...
}
```

By following these steps, your app should no longer crash, and you'll be able to use `parentViewModel` with its dependencies correctly injected. Ensure that your Dagger setup is providing the dependencies as required.

Comment: could you give an example of "// Inject your dependencies here" ? I don't understand how to pass the arguments to HomeViewModelFactory

Comment: Your class would need a "constructor that takes the dependencies variables" as arguments to "inject the values". Put the constructor in and the properties that are the arguments for the global's that will have the values injected!